# How to fix broken executable?

Tags: thunderbird, clamav

I ran a clamscan and got back the following:

```
$ clamscan --detect-broken=yes --scan-mail=yes -i -r ~/

/home/me/.thunderbird/u3mrythv.default/training.dat:
Heuristics.Broken.Executable FOUND

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------  
Known viruses: 4215681  
Engine version: 0.98.7  
Scanned directories: 9299  
Scanned files: 124155 
> Infected files: 1  
Total errors: 1  
Data scanned: 37139.78 MB  
Data read: 70573.71 MB (ratio 0.53:1)
Time: 2030.402 sec (33 m 50 s)
```

Do I need to fix this broken executable, and if so, how do I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to do anything. The file `training.dat` isn't an executable but contains training data for Thunderbird's spam filter.